# Zend3 iLike Search in Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework

I have data in my table, database Postgresql, which is both in lower and upper case, ex. 'Apple'.
I have a search input textfield. How can i convert the data in my database to lower case so that it returns 'Apple' when i type 'apple' in my textfield.

```
$select->where->like(Fruit::fruit_name, "%" . strtoupper($fruitName) . "%");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`expression`](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-db/sql/#expressionexpression-parameter) to do that, or just use `where` without like.

```
If you provide a string, this string will be used to create a Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression instance, and its contents will be applied as-is, with no quoting:
```

Have you tried the following:

```
$select->where(sprintf('%s iLIKE %%%s%%', Fruit::fruit_name, strtoupper($fruitName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have found a solution:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
$upperExpr = new Expression('LOWER(?)', [Fruit::fruit_name], [Expression::TYPE_IDENTIFIER]);
$select->where->like($upperExpr, "%" . mb_strtolower($fruitName, 'UTF-8') . "%");
```

Or only **strtolower()** if you have no 'äÄöÖüÜ' ;)

This will create the right SQL-Statement.